# "Integrate with Google" button suddenly disappeared (receiving 404)

Tags: google-apps, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I have Google-Apps-Marketplace app in which I'm using "Integrate with Google" button to start the google OAuth2 process.
For some unknown reason the button disappear today, and I'm receiving the error 404 - https://apis.google.com/marketplace/button

Does anybody know if it's a temporary issue in google API, or something had changed and I need to update my app?

I saw similar questions regarding the disappearance of the button from 4 years ago, however they refer there to access problems (error 403).
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: We are facing the same issue since a few hours ago, yesterday everything worked.

Comment: This might be a bug. You may check and report it through this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566262).

Comment: For those interested, the bug is opened [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110862188)

Comment: Seems like it was fixed, no comment from Google though.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the inconvenience, it was a temporary issue that has already been solved.

Comment: This is an insufficient answer not to mention that this problem just **recurred**.

Comment: It's been fixed again. We are working on migrating add-ons from Chrome Web Store to G Suite Marketplace. This affected only unpublished apps. GSM does not support installing unlisted apps. We'd like to better understand how this feature is being used.

Comment: Alejandro, do you plan to fix the problem for unpublished apps? and if the answer is yes, when do you estimate it will be ready?

Comment: Sorry I meant unlisted rather than unpublished. Chrome Web Store add-on for G Suite are being migrated to G Suite Marketplace. The systems have different features, e.g. GSM does not support unlisted apps so this caused some issues. It is fixed now.