# “Integrate with Google” button disappeared

Tags: google-apps, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I have GoogleApps Marketplace app in which I'm using "Integrate with Google" button to start the google OAuth2 process. The button disappeared two-ish days ago as far as I can tell. I'm receiving the error 404 - https://apis.google.com/marketplace/button

Is there a temporary issue in google API? I can update my app if needed as well. I've also made a ticket in Google's issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113072052 (inadvertently marked as a feature).

Exact same symptoms as: ["Integrate with Google" button suddenly disappeared (receiving 404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036762/integrate-with-google-button-suddenly-disappeared-receiving-404)

Comment: Same issue here with one of our apps, the other app however the flow if broken

Comment: If you're experiencing the issue, please comment here, so that google might notice: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113223810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be fixed now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

This affected only listings that are unlisted in Chrome Web Store. Installing unlisted apps is not supported in G Suite Marketplace and we would like to understand how/why you are using this feature.

Comment: I just let a comment on the issue tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113223810. Basically we use the Integrate with Google button as an easy/quick way to connect our app into customer's G Suite domain.

I've created an internal ticket to get our application published. With that said, I'm still not seeing the buttons come through. Wasn't sure if the fix should have already gone through.

Comment: Thanks Josh. The issue is now fixed.

Comment: @AlejandroTamalet seems that button issue is back again.

Comment: Yes, there was an issue, but it's fixed again.